# More search results in Chromium's address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

It seems like the address bar in Chromium only displays up to 6 search results... is there any way to make it display more?

Comment: I’ll see if I can find out. If it’s not possible you could always file a report/request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no setting available to change this.

The only way I can think of is to change the source code and compile a custom version... :-)

Comment: Do you happen to know where this is in the source code?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm using Firefox now, I would suggest to look at the directory structure and figure out where the search bar code could and couldn't be and then look around the places it could be. You should be looking into the function that gets called due to the key down event...

Comment: @Tom: I think I just found something, after a long semi-global search (`kMaxAutocompleteMenuItems` in `autocomplete_history_manager.cc` is 6, seems to be the right variable)... now time for a 5-hour recompile lol.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Build parallel and if this is a later build do an incremental build, also disable debug and tests. I would suggest reading the new value out of the registry if it is still possible, rather than hard-coding a value that might be bad...

Comment: @Tom: It's not the compile that takes a long time, it's the linking of chrome.dll; parallel builds don't really help. :\ (I only have a dual-core i5; I just do a single build with parallel compilers instead.) It's almost done though! :D

Comment: @Mehrdad: You could go for separated files instead. But well, if it's only once it could indeed be worth it... :)

Comment: @Tom: Eh, now it turns out the resources are messed up. For some reason `gsync` didn't work; time to gsync from scratch lol... (I have no idea how the heck people actually code programs like this; it takes Visual Studio more than a minute to just open and close the solution, and every `gsync` takes like 10 minutes, not to mention that builds take so many hours...)

Comment: Yeah, amazing programs like browsers are really code heavy...

Comment: @Tom: Lol, seems like that variable didn't do the trick...

Comment: Oh... `:` `-` `(`

Comment: Lol. BUT, on the bright side, I got a couple of other things to work that I wanted, so the build didn't go to waste. ;)